# Elasticsearch 5.0.2 with Django 1.8 and python 3.4 Issues with indexing

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am unable to find any method to get elasticsearch 5.0.2 to pull from my mariadb table to create an index. I have tried using multiple things from Honza's video from PyCon Aus that everyone recommends but dosnt work with 5.0.2 to elasticsearch-dsl 5.0 or different answers on here but none of it would even create the index let alone mirror the data. I am using Django 1.8.15 and python 3.4 and despertly looking for some guidance on this.

UPDATE:
So I found the following https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/docs/index.rst (seems they havnt updated the docs page yet) which helped work out some issues and I can now get the index created but putting data into it is still an issue with things such as object has no attribute 'copy'.

UPDATE 2:
This is currently the the point I am stuck at:
http://pastebin.com/tapGu6Vi

Comment: Try toggling Python version 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: I would rather not have legacy code in this project.